# Can nuts be frozen and for how long?

Tags: freezing, storage-lifetime, nuts

Can nuts be frozen in order to keep their flavour, and if so, for how long?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, just put them in a freezer bag and squeeze out plenty of air from it before you tie it up. It doesn't matter if they're shelled/crushed etc. You can keep them for as long as anything else - some say 6 months, some say a year, some say indefinitely.

Comment: We keep all raw nuts in the freezer now. Discovering that my container of pecans is rancid is too heartbreaking to bear.

Comment: Another +1. We routinely get cashews, peanuts, walnuts, almonds, and pistachios (as well as sunflower and pumpkin seeds), and keep them all in the freezer. I've never noticed any of them going off, although they rarely last more than a couple of months before getting used.

Answer (score 1):

I always freeze nuts of any kind, but I think they can get soft after awhile if they are frozen too long!I mean a long time, though...probably after a year they should be tossed...

Answer (score 1):

We always freeze our pecans and raw peanuts. I was shelling pecans tonight that I put in the freezer 14 years ago. this is December 2018, No problem with flavor or color. Sounds crazy but they will last indefinitely. Bud H.